# Mapping Error With DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am displaying categories in a dropdown list for adding products. When a product is to be added, you will have to select a category and Create Product or Update a previous product.

But my problem is that I get the following error:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList to a known managed provider
>   native type.

Database Diagram:
[image: Database Diagram Picture]

ASPX.:

```
    <p>Kategori</p>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDCategories" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

ASPX.CS.:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Dropdown Category Names From DB
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string sConstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LLcateringConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(sConstr);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("tbl");

                using (Conn)
                {
                    Conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Category", Conn);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

                DDCategories.DataSource = dt;
                DDCategories.DataTextField = "Name";
                DDCategories.DataBind();
            }
    }

 protected void BtnUpdateOrCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Text in fields has to exist, if they are requierd
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtName.Text) /*&&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtDescription.Text)*/)
        {
            // New the DataAccess and have all the parameteres here
            DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
            dataAccess.AddParameter("@Name", TxtName.Text);
            dataAccess.AddParameter("@Category_ID", DDCategories);
            dataAccess.AddParameter("@Description", TxtDescription.Text.ToNewline(false));
            dataAccess.AddParameter("@UnitPrice", TxtPrice.Text);
            dataAccess.AddParameter("@DiscountUnitPrice", TxtUnitDiscount.Text);

            if (isCreate)
            {
                // Insert query
                dataAccess.Execute(@"INSERT INTO [Product] ([Name], [Category_ID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountUnitPrice], [Description])
                                     VALUES (@Name, @Category_ID, @UnitPrice, @DiscountUnitPrice, @Description)
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.Product ON dbo.Category.ID = dbo.Product.Category_ID 
                                    ORDER BY [Name]
                                    WHERE id = @id");
            }
            else
            {
                // Update query
                dataAccess.AddParameter("@id", MenuID);
                dataAccess.Execute(@"UPDATE [Product]
                                    SET [Name] = @Name, [Category_ID] = @Category_ID, [UnitPrice] = @UnitPrice, [DiscountUnitPrice] = @DiscountUnitPrice, [Description] = @Description
                                    WHERE id = @id");
                                    //UPDATE [Product]
                                    //SET [Name] = @Name, [Category_ID] = @Category_ID, [UnitPrice] = @UnitPrice, [DiscountUnitPrice] = @DiscountUnitPrice, [Description] = @Description
                                    //INNER JOIN dbo.Product ON dbo.Category.ID = dbo.Product.Category_ID 
                                    //ORDER BY [Name]
                                    //WHERE id = @id");
            }

            // Redirects to list
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
        }
        else
            LitStatus.Text = "Hey så indtast da noget!";
    }
```

Comment: What are you aming to achieve with this statement?    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

Comment: @Lloyd, to be redirected back to the page with all the products listed. But I can't see if it works because of the error I get above when clicking "Update" or "Create".

Comment: You are redirecting back on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this line
`dataAccess.AddParameter("@Category_ID", DDCategories);`
and replace with
`dataAccess.AddParameter("@Category_ID", DDCategories.SelectedValue)`

Comment: replacing the above code does make the error go away! (great news), but it tells me there's something wrong with my query inside the   // Insert query "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.".

Comment: @MikeBertelsen - the join+order by+where in the insert looks strange. Isn't that a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @PHeiberg Haha, no no I actually tried to write that but I have never JOINED something in an INSERT and UPDATE query.. Honestly I can't really understand it.

Comment: @MikeBertelsen - In order to insert a new product you don't need any data from Category, the category id is coming from the user selection. Get rid of the join and try the statement in the Query Analyser before trying to use it in your program code. That will save you a lot of time. You can't join in that way for an inserts. If you actually have to join data for an INSERT, you must SELECT the data first and pass that data in to the INSERT. Also you can't have a WHERE clause after an ORDER BY.

Comment: @PHeiberg oh I see, I removed the JOIN and it made the error go away, although I now get "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Konfirmation' to data type int.", where Konfirmation is a Category from the DropDownList. Ps. I like your simple and easy way of explaining things, thumps up.

Comment: ^^ Problem above was a simple mistake, I displayed NAME inside my DropDown instead of ID.